# LibGDX Texture setWrap method doesn't repeat

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

Hello I'm tring to make a neverending background. So I try to wrap my texture.

```
texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
```

And draw it:

```
bach.begin();
bach.draw(texture, 0, 0);
bach.end();
```

I'm ending with no changes to the texture when I use setWrap.

If i draw the texture that way:

```
bach.begin();
bach.draw(texture, 0, 0, texture.width, texture.height, 0, 0, 1, 1);
bach.end();
```

It repeats the texture but flipped...

If I try to flip the y and x in the bach.draw I get an error.

I only can flip the camera but then the position y flips too (translating up goes negative value / translating down goes positive value)

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a texture, you need it to use UVs bigger than one, which you can do with a TextureRegion that is bigger than the Texture it references.

```
TextureRegion backgroundTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture, bgWidth, bgHeight);

//...

batch.begin();
batch.draw(backgroundTextureRegion, 0, 0, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
batch.end();
```

Where `bgWidth` and `bgHeight` are how many texels wide and high you want to draw the background. For instance, if your camera's `viewportWidth` is 1920 and you want your texture to be drawn at 1:1 scale (texture pixels : camera units), then `bgWidth` would be 1920.

If you need to flip it vertically, you can use `-bgHeight` instead without messing with the camera.

Comment: Thanks great help! One Question: How could I do the Infinite background effect? Warp the texture allways to the screen middel if it's on the edge and Repeat it on the left and right side?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: He wants to scroll and have the end of the texture be sewn to the start I guess.